# UIImage with NSData without size

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, size, nsdata

I have this code:

```
...
NSData * dimage = [[NSData alloc]initWithData:[datosImagen objectForKey:@"Image"]];
UIImage * imagenAMostrar = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:dimage];
UIImageView * imAMostrar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imagenAMostrar];
...
```

I need resize my UIImageView, similar to this dimensions: `setFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,320,240)`.
but for this i need UIImageView size....

```
NSLog(@" Image width:%d",imagenAMostrar.size.width);
NSLog(@" Image height:%d",imagenAMostrar.size.height);
```

The result is:

```
2011-10-03 13:32:28.993 Catalogo-V1[2679:207] Image width:0
2011-10-03 13:32:28.994 Catalogo-V1[2679:207] Image height:0
```

Why??

Comment: you can check first if your image object is created or not first like this `if([UIImage imageWithData:dimage])`

Comment: Do not ignore warnings, they are there to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you get any warnings in *NSLog* statements? You should be getting a conversion type warnings. *`width`* and *`height`* are *`float-s`*. You are supposed to use `%f` as conversion specifier. You should be printing them like this,

```
NSLog(@" Image width:%f", imagenAMostrar.size.width);
NSLog(@" Image height:%f", imagenAMostrar.size.height);
```

You can set the *frame* of image view like this,

```
imAMostrar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, imagenAMostrar.size.width, imagenAMostrar.size.height);
```